# Java (ArrayList check with object's int)

Tags: java, arraylist

I have to make an `ArrayList` that contains an object, the object has one `int for year` lets say 1
and I don't what another object with the same year 1.

If one object has the int = 1 , i dont want another object with that int(1) in my list.
i want to deny it.

Should I try using equal?

something like

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o){
    Object object = (Object)o;
    return this.getInt.equals(object.getInt());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Either use a `Set`...which explicitly disallows duplicates, or check if the list contains the element on insertion.

```
@Override
public boolean add(T element) {
    if(contains(element)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return super.add(element);
    }
}
```

Overriding `equals` wouldn't get you very far, as you'd be overriding it for the `List` itself (i.e. you'd be checking if two lists were equal).

Comment: How does that work? i care only about the one int that the Object has, if it has 2 ints, how does this work? i need both ints to be equal to make it count as a duplicated?

Comment: If the list contains the element, then you don't want to add it.  You're not invoking `equals` on the list itself; you want `equals` invoked on the object you're passing in.  I'd reference the documentation for `List.contains` to see how it really works.  (You'd also want the `equals` method to be well-defined for your use case on the entity you pass in - this is why I used a generic type instead of `Object`.)

Comment: Prefer composition over inheritance. You're missing addAll, retainAll, add(int, Object).

Comment: @SteveKuo The example was meant to be informative rather than be feature complete.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try using a HashMap linked that links that "int" with the object. That could be:

```
Map<Integer, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(object.getInt(), object);
...
//Each time you put a new object you could try this:
if(!map.contains(object.getInt()))
    map.put(object.getInt, object);
//And you can retrieve your object by an int
int a = 1;
Object obj = map.get(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, as the value is of type int, you can use equal operator.

```
public boolean equals(Object o){
    Object object = (Object)o;
    return (this.getInt()==object.getInt());
}
```

For this kind of requirement, ArrayList is not suggestible. As mentioned in the other answers try using HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. When you call

```
myArrayList.contains(myObejct);
```

the ArrayList will invode myObejct's equals method. So you can tell if the object is already in you list.
And I think you can change you method a little,

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o){
    if (!(o instanceof YourClass))  
        return false;
    YourClass object = (YourClass)o;
    return this.getInt.equals(object.getInt());
}
```

because if you don't, the method "getInt" might cause a MethodNotFound exception.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is one way to approach the problem.

- Your `equals` will probably work provided that you change `Object object = (Object)o;` to cast to the real class.
- However, `equals` ought to cope with the case where `o` is not of the expected type.  The contract requires you should return `false` rather than throwing a `ClassCastException` ...

You would then use `list.contains(o)` to test if an object with the same `int` value exists in the list.  For example:

```
    if (!list.contains(o)) {
        list.add(o);
    }
```

But when you override `equals`, it is best practice to also override `hashcode` ... so that your class continues to satisfy the equals / hashcode invariants.  (If you neglect to do that, hash-based data structures will break for your class.)

---

However, this won't scale well, because the `contains` operation on an `ArrayList` has to test each element in the list, one at a time.  As the list gets longer, the `contains` call takes longer ... in direct proportion; i.e. `O(N)` ... using Big O complexity notation.

So it may be better to use a `Set` implementation of some kind instead on `ArrayList`.  Fepending on which set implementation you choose, you will get complexity of `O(1)` or `O(logN)`.  But the catch is that you will either *have to* to implement `hashcode` (for a `HashSet` or `LinkedHashSet`), or implement either `Comparable` or a `Comparator` (for a `TreeSet`).